# RestTemplate with HTTPS (Accept all Certificate)

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

Trying to call a REST API from Springboot applicaiton which runs on HTTPS and I am getting the javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException. Referred some code here and tried with below code and it's not working. appreciate any help. Tried from SOAP UI which works perfectly. SOAP UI is automatically downloading/accepting the complete certificate chain. I want to exact thing with Spring RestTemplate.

```
import org.apache.http.conn.socket.LayeredConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class RestClientDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        RestClientDemo restClientDemo = new RestClientDemo();
        restClientDemo.callRestAPI();
    }

    private String callRestAPI() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        final String uri = "https://tidalsn:8443/api/tes-SandBox/postbody";
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier()).build();
        HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory((LayeredConnectionSocketFactory) getSSLSocketFactory());
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic S01IUFxzZzIwNjYwOkNoZXRhbkAxMjM=");
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        };
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    }
}
```

Here is the Exception:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
    at com.amerihealthcaritas.tidal.util.Test.callRestAPI(Test.java:37)
    at com.amerihealthcaritas.tidal.util.Test.main(Test.java:25)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:89)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 33 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public RestTemplate getRestTemplateForHttps() throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
    SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(5 * 1000);
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    return restTemplate;
}
```

Comment: This should solve most https calls, never had a problem, you can customize the headers and the read / connect timeout as desired

Comment: Add your above comment in your answer itself, along with any additional explanation of the code that you have shown. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a SSL SocketFactory and pass it to the HttpClients.

```
   private SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory() {         
      TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

                return true;
            }
        };

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
  }
```

You can then set it to

```
HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());
```

I think this should sole the issue.

Comment: Hi Varesh, I tried it and I am getting class cast exception.  HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory is expecting LayeredConnectionSocketFactory. I have added my complete class can you please take a look?

Comment: I guess the issue is just with the right class of SSLSocketFactory... but I think you have figured out anyways. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working fine for me and it's accepting all the certificates.

```
TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic S01IUFxzZzIwNjsssYwOkNoZXRhbkAxMjM=");
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(xmlString, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class);
        return response.getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for httpcomponents 5**

The previous solutions given were OK for httpcomponent 4 but are not working with httpcomponent 5.

The migration guide of httpcomponent 5 gives advices to convert the code: [Migration to Apache HttpClient 5.0 classic APIs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/migration-guide/migration-to-classic.html)

This method allows to trust all SSL certificates with RestTemplate (org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.2) and httpcomponents 5 (org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1):

```
public RestTemplate getRestTemplateWithTrustStrategy() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
    
    TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
                .setSslContext(SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build())
                .setTlsVersions(TLS.V_1_3, TLS.V_1_2)
                .build())
        .setDefaultSocketConfig(SocketConfig.custom()
                .setSoTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5))
                .build())
        .setPoolConcurrencyPolicy(PoolConcurrencyPolicy.STRICT)
        .setConnPoolPolicy(PoolReusePolicy.LIFO)
        .setDefaultConnectionConfig(ConnectionConfig.custom()
                .setTimeToLive(TimeValue.ofMinutes(1L))
                .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5))
                .build())
        .build();

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                .setResponseTimeout(Timeout.ofSeconds(5))
                .setCookieSpec(StandardCookieSpec.STRICT)
                .build())
        .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);

    return new RestTemplate(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory);
}
```